# feval error with window function

Tags: matlab

I have a problem with this error:

**Error using feval**

> Argument must contain a string or function_handle.

**Error in window (line 54)**

> w = feval(wname,N,varargin{:});

and this is a window function:

```
function varargout = window(wname,N,varargin)
%WINDOW Window function gateway.
%   WINDOW(@WNAME,N) returns an N-point window of type specified
%   by the function handle @WNAME in a column vector.  @WNAME can
%   be any valid window function name, for example:
%
%   @bartlett       - Bartlett window.
%   @barthannwin    - Modified Bartlett-Hanning window. 
%   @blackman       - Blackman window.
%   @blackmanharris - Minimum 4-term Blackman-Harris window.
%   @bohmanwin      - Bohman window.
%   @chebwin        - Chebyshev window.
%   @flattopwin     - Flat Top window.
%   @gausswin       - Gaussian window.
%   @hamming        - Hamming window.
%   @hann           - Hann window.
%   @kaiser         - Kaiser window.
%   @nuttallwin     - Nuttall defined minimum 4-term Blackman-Harris window.
%   @parzenwin      - Parzen (de la Valle-Poussin) window.
%   @rectwin        - Rectangular window.
%   @taylorwin      - Taylor window.
%   @tukeywin       - Tukey window.
%   @triang         - Triangular window.
%
%   WINDOW(@WNAME,N,OPT1,OPT2) designs the window with the optional input
%   arguments specified in OPT1 and OPT2. To see what the optional input
%   arguments are, see the help for the individual windows, for example,
%   KAISER or CHEBWIN.
%
%   WINDOW launches the Window Design & Analysis Tool (WinTool).
%
%   EXAMPLE: 
%      N  = 100;
%      w  = window(@blackmanharris,N);
%      w1 = window(@gausswin,N,2.5);
%      w2 = window(@taylorwin,N,5,-35);
%      plot(1:N,[w,w1,w2]); axis([1 N 0 2]);
%      legend('Blackman-Harris','Gaussian','Taylor');
% 
%   See also BARTLETT, BARTHANNWIN, BLACKMAN, BLACKMANHARRIS, BOHMANWIN, 
%            CHEBWIN, GAUSSWIN, HAMMING, HANN, KAISER, NUTTALLWIN, PARZENWIN, 
%            RECTWIN, TAYLORWIN, TRIANG, TUKEYWIN, WINTOOL.

%    Author(s): P. Costa 
%    Copyright 1988-2008 The MathWorks, Inc.
%    $Revision: 1.14.4.2 $  $Date: 2008/07/09 18:13:44 $ 

if nargin == 0,
    wintool;
    w = [];
else
    % Create an N-point window specified in wname
    error(nargchk(2,inf,nargin,'struct')); % Function handle and order are required
    w = feval(wname,N,varargin{:});
end

if nargout > 0,
    varargout{1} = w;
end

% [EOF]
```

Comment: The code you show is Matlab's `window` function. Unless you tell us how you are calling that function, it's hard for us to tell what the cause of the error is

Comment: A call of the window () function is: mask_use = window (mask_code, chipsamples, length(mask_code)/chipsamples, floor(Tm/dt), floor(Tm/dt)*P_gain);

Answer (score 0):

The use of feval is bad style because it makes your code less readable. I would suggest, not to call your window function with a string containing the function name for `wname` parameter but rather with a function handle as suggested in your documentation.
You can then replace your `feval` statement by:

```
w = wname(N,varargin{:});
```

When you call your `window()` function you have to pass the function handle, not the name:

```
window(@bartlett,N)
```

This will work if the function `bartlett()` is defined somewhere else.

If you are not able to change the calling code of `window()` just take care to call the function correctly, as shown above or alternatively with

```
window('bartlett',N)
```

In both cases the function 'bartlett' must be defined!

Comment: thank you for your answer. My call of the window () function is:                        mask_use = window (mask_code, chipsamples, length(mask_code)/chipsamples, floor(Tm/dt), floor(Tm/dt)*P_gain);

Comment: @sondes: obviously `mask_code` is neither a string nor a function handle. But the first argument of window() MUST be a function handle or the name of a defined function. Otherwise it won't run.